# Query builder GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-6

how to express this code in query builder. I'm using Laravel 6.

```
SELECT * FROM feedback GROUP BY noTicket having count(`status`) < 2
```

My Code:

```
$feedback = DB::table('feedback')
            ->groupBy('noTicket')
            ->having('count(status)', '<', 2)
            ->get();
```

Error Code:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'sifora.feedback.idFeedback' isn't in GROUP BY 
(SQL: select * from `feedback` group by `noTicket` having `count(status)` < 2)
```

What is wrong with my code? It seems match between sql code vs query builder.

Thank you

Comment: Unless you group by all columns, `SELECT *` and `GROUP BY` is not valid and make no sense. Also I doubt there is a column `count(status)`.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by your query?

Comment: @party-ring: This mysql query already tested on Navicat and work perfectly. I want to group all same noTicket and choose noTicket which status < 2.

Comment: @Ikra please share your table structure, sample data to reproduce it and expected result. Your query is incompatible because of group by.

Comment: @Ersoy: My ticketing concept is, if someone created ticket and replied, it will store in feedback table. New ticket marked by status=1, assigned ticket marked by status=2. I want to display new ticket only which is status = 1 AND not assign yet. Because 1 noTicket can have multiple response and status will generate from 1 (waiting for response), 2 (In progress), 3 (completed), 4 (closed)

Example

noTicket = 4 --> My window was broken --> status = 1
noTicket = 4 --> Ok we will check and repair --> status = 2

so, noTicket = 4 can't show up in new ticket(s)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the working version of query

```
select noTicket
from feedback
group by noTicket
having count(status) < 2;
```

This is the query builder;

```
return DB::table('feedback')
    ->groupBy('noTicket')
    ->having(DB::raw('count(status)'), '<', 2)
    ->pluck('noTicket'); // you may replace this with get()/select()
```

Comment: Almost correct. The output are correct but not display all data. The output are in array. If use pluck, the output are [2,3] which is noTicket = 2 and noTicket = 3. If use get, the output are [noTicket = 2, noTicket = 3]. Thank you before

Comment: as mentioned in the answer you can use `->get('noTicket')` or `->select('noTicket')->get()`. If you don't do this the query builder will assume you want to `select *`

Comment: @Ikra - also Hazem pointed out- i appended alternatives as comment to answer. It depends on how you want to display.

Comment: @HazemMohamed: yes I already tried all alternative options as comment. I've got an error if I only use `->get` and `->pluck`. On the other hand if I use `->get('noTicket')` the result is in array ex: [2,3,5]. So I need to select where in array. Is there any easy way to get all data? thank you before

Comment: @Ersoy: i've got error when I used `->get()` , `->pluck()`, `->select()`. There was no error if I used `->get('noTicket`) or `->pluck('noTicket')` but the result not show all data. If used `->select('noTicket')` no error but get data as I'm not expected. So I used `pluck('noTicket')` to get value and then need to select where in array to retrieve all data. Is there any easy way to get all data? Thank you..

Answer (score 2):

Here the complete code. Thanks a lot to Ersoy

```
        $getArray = DB::table('feedback')
            ->groupBy('noTicket')
            ->having(DB::raw('count(status)'), '<', 2)
            ->pluck('noTicket');
        $feedback = DB::table('feedback')
            ->whereIn('noTicket', $getArray)->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$feedback  = DB::table('feedback')
    ->selectRaw('feedback.*, count(status) as count_status')
    ->groupBy('noTicket')
    ->havingRaw('count(status) > ?', [2])
    ->get();
```

Also there exists strict mode, you can disable it in config/database.php

```
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        'strict' => false
    ]
]
```

But I don't recommend to you to do it. Check this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html here you get more info how group by works.